# CSS height problem: display a non-normalised height that does not follow the aspect ratio of the container

Tags: html, css

Image of the problem:
[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqGBW.png)

If you look the previous image, you will see that I have an enormous blank space there. When I have my normal display (1200px aprox) it is fine. However, when width is being reduced, that blank space is increasing always, and I don't know why is this happening.

Image of the normal display of the screen:
[image of normal display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy8Fh.png)

I will upload a part of the html and css code in order to have the code clearly written.

```css
.about-me{
margin-top: 10px;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
height: 100vh;
}

.about-me h1{
color: goldenrod;
text-align: center;
font-size: 52px;
}

.about-me .about{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.about-me .about .text-container{
max-width: 70%;
}

.about-me .about .text-container p{
font-size: 24px;
text-align: center;
margin: 50px;
}

.about-me .about .text-container span{
color: goldenrod;
font-weight: 900;
}

.border{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;

border: 1px solid goldenrod;
background-color: goldenrod;
border-radius: 50%;

margin: 0 50px;
max-width: 100%;
}

.about-me .border img{
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
border-radius: 50%;
scale: 95%;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="about-me" id="about-me">
    <h1>WHAT ARE WE?</h1>
    <div class="about">
        <div class="text-container">
            <p>text</p>

            <p>text</p>

            <p>text</p>
        </div>

        <div class="border">
            <img src="img/arcos.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the `height` of `.about-me` section to `100vh` fixed. It is the reason why you are getting that long blank space.

```
.about-me{
    /* height: 100vh; */
}
```

Edit: For maintaining the dimension you can use the height on the `.border` container to cover the 100% viewport height and for smaller screens use `height: auto` so that the height can be decreased in proportion to the screen width.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 802px){
    .border{
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
    .about-me{
    margin-top: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    /* height: 100vh; */
}

.about-me h1{
    color: goldenrod;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 52px;
}

.about-me .about{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.about-me .about .text-container{
    max-width: 70%;
}

.about-me .about .text-container p{
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px;
}

.about-me .about .text-container span{
    color: goldenrod;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.border{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    border: 1px solid goldenrod;
    background-color: goldenrod;
    border-radius: 50%;

    margin: 0 50px;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 71px);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 802px){
    .border{
        height: auto;
    }
}

.about-me .border img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    scale: 95%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="about-me" id="about-me">
    <h1>WHAT ARE WE?</h1>
    <div class="about">
        <div class="text-container">
            <p>text</p>

            <p>text</p>

            <p>text</p>
        </div>

        <div class="border">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1500/1500?random=1" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background: grey;">footer</footer>
```

Comment: It works. However, if I do that the containers won't have the same dimension (which is something that I want). In that case, if I conserve the height: 100vh, I suppose that I should add the responsive correctly in order to have the same dimensions in all the containers, right?

Comment: I also have a solution to maintain that dimension. I have updated my answer. Please check.